# TypeError: Class constructor CryptoFactory cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5, hyperledger-sawtooth

I want to use the sawtooth-sdk, and the guide code (https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/releases/latest/_autogen/sdk_submit_tutorial_js.html):

```
const {createContext, CryptoFactory} = require('sawtooth-sdk/signing')

const context = createContext('secp256k1')
const privateKey = context.newRandomPrivateKey()
const signer = CryptoFactory(context).newSigner(privateKey)
```

but error:

```
TypeError: Class constructor CryptoFactory cannot be invoked without 'new'
```

Comment: From the error message, the linked page is wrong, and the error is telling you clearly what to do instead. Did you try doing that?

Comment: It looks like it is a class and you have to do:
const factory = new CryptoFactory(context);
const signer = facory.newSigner(privateKey);

Comment: `const signer = new CryptoFactory(context).newSigner(privateKey)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error states, you should change:

```
const signer = CryptoFactory(context).newSigner(privateKey)
```

to:

```
const signer = (new CryptoFactory(context)).newSigner(privateKey)
```